# Paper '12mm' is not supported by 'DYMO LabelWriter DUO Label

Tags: vb.net, printing, sdk, dymo

I'm working on a small project that requires printing directly to a DYMO printer using their SDK. I've made other projects before using the same method:

- Find DYMO
- Get .label file
- Set label variable object(s)
- Print label

However, I receive the following error from the VB.NET program when calling the `label.Print()` method:

**Paper '12mm' is not supported by 'DYMO LabelWriter DUO Label'**

I receive the error delayed, so I'm assuming that the `Print()` method runs in a separate thread. Therefore I'm also assuming that the error occurs in the `Print()` method. This method is also the only point that the `Label` and `IPrinter` objects are provided in a single method according to the list above.

This error does not make sense, as the DYMO software has successfully printed labels using the same .label template. Is there possibly an incompatibility issue with the V8.+ of the SDK/Software and this model? If so, how/where can I determine a compatible version?

Insight on the fixing the error would be greatly appreciated or even any leads on documentation of error handlers with the DYMO SDK (all I've found are old samples of how to use the SDK).

Comment: The print method returns void and according to the tooltip in visual studio, it does not throw exceptions. So it sends a print command to the printer, but how can you troubleshoot this? How did you receive the notice from the unsupported paper?

Comment: After my application crashed a few times, I threw a Try..Catch around the print command. The catch message provided the text labeled in my question.

Comment: Can you show the code. Do you provide additional arguments to the `Print()` method?

Comment: Probably something wrong with you labelXML. Did you create it with DYMO Label Software? Or did you code it by yourself?